# Inject String with qualifier in CDI

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld

I'm trying to do simple thing. Inject qualified `String` (or `File`) in CDI.

So I have a qualifier:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE})
@Qualifier
public @interface FilesRepositoryPath {}
```

I have a producer:

```
public class FilesRepositoryPathProducer {

  @Produces
  @FilesRepositoryPath
  public String getRepositoryDirectory() {
    return "path.taken.from.configuration";
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FilesRepository {

  @Inject
  public FilesRepository(@FilesRepositoryPath String filesDirectory) {
    //Do some stuff
  }
}
```

However, WELD cannot instantiate this bean. I am getting an exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.impl.event.FiredEventException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001410 The injection point [field] @Inject private za.co.fnb.commercial.dms.file.FilesRepositoryBeanTest.repo has non-proxyable dependencies
```

I know `String` is unproxable, but why WELD wants to create a proxy? It has `@Dependent` scope, so AFAIK it shouldn't create proxy anyway. How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you post `FilesRepositoryBeanTest` please?

Comment: file an issue in Weld. The code seems OK according to the spec.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583871/injecting-a-named-string-using-cdi, seems to be a similar problem

Answer (score 3):

you need the default constructor

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FilesRepository {

  public FilesRepository() {
  }

  @Inject
  public FilesRepository(@FilesRepositoryPath String filesDirectory) {
    //Do some stuff
  }
}
```